# Hibernate 6.0 CreateTable Issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a following code in a pre Hibernate

```
Table table = namespace.locateTable(qualifiedTableName.getObjectName());
if (table == null) {
    table = namespace.createTable(qualifiedTableName.getObjectName(), false);
}
```

In hibernate 6.0 the signature of create table is changed to:

```
 public Table createTable(Identifier logicalTableName, Function<Identifier, Table> creator);
```

So it does not support the boolean type anymore. I am trying to find any sample of createTable instance in web for hibernate 6.0, but nothing useful was found. Could you please share any ideas or resources about the createTable with the new signature.